# Best way to share a Gmail account - possibly imported into a forum?

Tags: rss, gmail, phpbb

I run a website which uses a private phpBB forum to manage staff discussions.

We have a gmail address for news submissions. All staff have access to this inbox.

I'd love to think up a smart way to import the emails from this address into our forum. Gmail offer an RSS feed (http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/inbox_feed.html#inbox) which could make this possible.

Can anyone think of a clever way to make it so these emails could be viewable from the forum without people having to check both the account and the message board?

It doesn't have to be phpBB specific, but this is the setup I'm using.

Thanks, and sorry for the fairly vague concept.
Matt

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me what you mean. You can use the php IMAP extension to POP email from POP boxes. Gmail supports that. However, I would suggest not to dive into that world.

I would advise to change the way users can submit news. If you're able to manage phpBB, then I guess you're able to setup PHP+MySQL. You could e.g. create a simple PHP form and store news submissions in a database and create a page where staff members can view the submissions.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, never mind - I'll just write a script to parse the RSS feed and spit it into a phpBB forum using their API. thanks!

Comment: Now I re-read your question, I understand much better what you mean. Never mind my "answer" :)